# Uniqueness of ODE solution with Dirichlet conditions on the half line

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this ODE problem $-u''(x)=(1-u^2(x))u(x)$ where $x \in  (0,{\infty})$  and $u \in C^2 (0,{\infty}) \cap C [0,{\infty})$ ,
with the initial condition $u(0)=0$,

I have proved the existence of a solution, but i have  trouble  proving its uniqueness .

This is a crucial part to complete my thesis,

I would be very thankful if you can help.

Comment: you may want look up gradient equation. these have the total energy $e = \frac12u'^2 + \frac12u^2 - \frac18u^4$ is conserved on the trajectories.

Comment: That should be $1/4$, not $1/8$.

Answer (score 0):

For uniqueness of a second-order differential equation you generally need two initial conditions, typically $u(0) = \ldots$ and $u'(0) = \ldots$.
In this case, solutions other than $u = 0$ are
$$ u(x) = c \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{c^2+1}} \text{sn} \left(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{c^2+1}},c\right) $$ 
for arbitrary real $c$, where $\text{sn}$ is a Jacobi elliptic function.  In particular, for $c=\pm 1$ this is $\pm \tanh(x/\sqrt{2})$, corresponding to 
$u'(0) = \pm 1/\sqrt{2}$.  If $|u'(0)| > 1/\sqrt{2}$, it seems the solutions blow up at a finite value of $x$, but if $0 < |u'(0)| < 1/\sqrt{2}$ you get a periodic solution with a real value of $c$.

Comment: Thanks a lot,
Is there a chance to have uniqueness under these conditions only $u(0)=0$ and $u(x)\to1$ when $x\to+ \infty$?
Because i have no conditions on $u'(0)$ and it is stated in a paper that there is a unique solution for the following ODE problem
$−u′′(x) = f(u(x)), ∀x ∈ R^{+∗} ,
u(0) = 0, u′(0) > 0,
u′ > 0, 0 < u < 1\,in\,R^{+∗}$
where $f$ be a Lipschitz-continuous function in $[0, 1] $such that $ f(0) = f(1) = 0$
and f is nonincreasing in $[1 − δ, 1]$ for some $δ > 0$,
$∀ 0 ≤ s < 1$,
$\int_{s}^{1} 
{f(τ )}\,dτ >0$,which is my case taking $f(u)=(1-u^2)u$

Comment: Additional condition on this DE $\lim_{x\to{+\infty}}\,{u(x)}=1$

Comment: Yes, with the additional condition, the only solution is $u(x) = \tanh(x/\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate your help,

Comment: Is there any references for the uniqueness proof,because ive been asked  to give the proof details,its obligatory, i tried hard to find it but i couldnt till now

Comment: abel's hint about conservation of total energy is a good clue (except for the wrong coefficient).  What must the energy be in order for $u(x) \to 1$?